# iOS: How to ensure cell maintains its colour when reuse cells are on

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm building an app where my tableview cells transition in colour from Red to Dark blue (Hot to Cold), this dictates an order of priority for tasks to be completed in.

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I have written some logic to ensure that the color of each cell is equal depending on the size of a task collection.  The problem I am facing is that my global variables which track the current index mutate each time a new cell is generated, meaning my cells all become one block color at some given point (as the user scrolls).

Here is my current global code:

```
// Difference is calculated by dividing the bgColors size by the task collection size
var currDiff = 0
var currIndex = 0

var tasks = [PFObject]()
var bgColors = [
    UIColor(red: 255, green: 51, blue: 51),
    UIColor(red: 255, green: 153, blue: 51),
    UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 51),
    UIColor(red: 153, green: 255, blue: 51),
    UIColor(red: 102, green: 255, blue: 51),
    UIColor(red: 51, green: 255, blue: 204),
    UIColor(red: 51, green: 204, blue: 255),
    UIColor(red: 51, green: 102, blue: 255),
]
```

Then here is the portion from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which sets the colours based on the collection size:

```
    // Compute the cell colour
    let totalCells = tasks.count
    let totalColors = bgColors.count

    // If we exceed the number of colours, then evenly distribute them
    if(totalCells > totalColors) {
        let diff = Int(ceil(CGFloat(totalCells) / CGFloat(totalColors)))
        if(currDiff > diff) {
            currDiff = 0
            currIndex++
        }

        if currIndex < 0 {
            currIndex = 0
        }
        if(currIndex >= bgColors.count) {
            currIndex = 0
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = bgColors[currIndex]
        currDiff++
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = bgColors[indexPath.row]
    }
```

In the scenario that I had 28 tasks in a collection and 8 colors, this code would compute 28 / 8 = 3.5 and then round it to 4, this would then render blocks of 4 by using currDiff to track the amount of cells rendered in that specific colour, and currIndex to track which index in the array we are.

I hope this makes sense, if any further details are needed please ask.

Comment: You need to base the index on the `indexPath` of the cell, not on some other variable.

Comment: Surely if I used something like `indexPath.row` to get the colour from my `bgColors` array, and I went past the max count of `bgColors` then my application would crash...I'm not sure how else to solve it

Comment: I'm not clear on how the colors are to be used but you must come up with a formula that converts the cell's `indexPath.row` into the desired index into `bgColors`. And the calculation needs to work regardless of what order cells are used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll head back to the drawing board...just for clarification the colours would be like `red, yellow, pink green` and they would be evenly dispersed based on the collection size, so if I had 8 colors in the array, every 4 cells would be of the color at the current index

Comment: That confuses me even more. In your question's code you have 8 colors. Let's say you have 16 rows in the table. Would the rows be colored with colors 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or would they be colored with colors 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7?

Comment: They would be coloured as  0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the colors evenly distributed through the rows of the table, you can do some simple math on the cell's `indexPath.row` to calculate the needed color index.

I'm not proficient in Swift so the following syntax could be a bit off but it should be close:

```
var colorIndex = Int((CGFloat(indexPath.row) / CGFloat(tasks.count)) * CGFloat(bgColors.count));
```

The first part gives you the percentage through the table for the given row and then that percentage is applied to the color count.

Keep in mind that if the number of rows isn't a whole multiple of the color count, then obviously not every color will appear the same number of times.

Comment: This worked perfectly...trust me to completely over-think the entire problem.  Thanks a lot :)